# Authenticating with public key in javascript

Tags: javascript, webauthn

I'm try to follow instructions at https://webauthn.guide to register biometric login for a user in my site.

The register Javascript function is this:

```
var randomStringFromServer = "123456";
async function CreateANew()
{
    var bz = Uint8Array.from(randomStringFromServer);
    const publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions = {
        challenge: bz,
    rp: {
        name: "mysite.COM",
        id: "mysite.com",
    },
    user: {
        id: Uint8Array.from(
            'some_user_name'),
        name: 'some_name',
        displayName: 'some_display_name',
    },
    pubKeyCredParams: [{alg: -7, type: "public-key"}],
    authenticatorSelection: {
        
    },
    timeout: 60000,
    attestation: "direct"
};
   const credential = await navigator.credentials.create({
    publicKey: publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions
    });
    if (!credential)
        return;
    
    // decode the clientDataJSON into a utf-8 string
    const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
    const decodedClientData = utf8Decoder.decode(credential.response.clientDataJSON);
    // parse the string as an object
    const clientDataObj = JSON.parse(decodedClientData);
    
    const decodedAttestationObj = CBOR.decode(
        credential.response.attestationObject);


        const {authData} = decodedAttestationObj;

        // get the length of the credential ID
        const dataView = new DataView(
            new ArrayBuffer(2));
        const idLenBytes = authData.slice(53, 55);
        idLenBytes.forEach(
            (value, index) => dataView.setUint8(
                index, value));
        const credentialIdLength = dataView.getUint16();

        // get the credential ID
        const credentialId = authData.slice(
            55, 55 + credentialIdLength);

        // get the public key object
        const publicKeyBytes = authData.slice(
            55 + credentialIdLength);

        // the publicKeyBytes are encoded again as CBOR
        const publicKeyObject = CBOR.decode(
            publicKeyBytes.buffer);
                        

    let CID = credentialId;
    let PID = publicKeyBytes;
    console.log(credentialId);
    $.ajax({
        url: "bio.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {"create": 2, "type": <?= $tyx ?>, "uid" : <?= $u ?>, "challenge": clientDataObj.challenge, "origin": clientDataObj.origin,"ctype": clientDataObj.type,"authData": decodedAttestationObj.authData,"fmt" : decodedAttestationObj.fmt, "credentialID" : CID, "publicKeyBytes" : PID },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#result").html(result);
            if (result.startsWith("OK"))
                window.location = "bio.php";
        }
    });
```

This works, I get back a `credentialID` and a `publicKeyBytes` array in my PHP database.

```
<?php

 $ar = serialize($_POST['credentialID']); // and then store $ar to database
```

When however I'm trying to authenticate the user:

```
// $or = PHP array with the credentialID taken from the database
// $or = unserialize(...);
async function Login()
    {
        var bz = Uint8Array.from(randomStringFromServer);
        let id2 = "<?= implode(",",$or) ?>";
        let id2a = id2.replace(/, +/g, ",").split(",").map(Number);
        let id3 =  Uint8Array.from(id2a);
        console.log(id3);

        const publicKeyCredentialRequestOptions = {
        challenge: bz,                
        allowCredentials: [{
            id: id3,
            type: 'public-key',
            
        }],
timeout: 60000,
```

}

```
    const credential = await navigator.credentials.get({
        publicKey: publicKeyCredentialRequestOptions
    });
}
```

This time I only get an 'insert your USB key' in Chrome. It seems not to recognize my credentialID.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the credential ID is getting corrupted somewhere along the way. Try logging to to the console just after extracting it:

```js
console.log(btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(CID)));
```

And again just before making the authentication call:

```js
console.log(btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(id3)));
```

They should be the same value.

---

As an aside:

> user: {
> id: Uint8Array.from('some_user_name'),

The user.id [should not include any identifiable information](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#sctn-user-handle-privacy), so a user name is a bad value there. I recommend generating a per-user, 128-bit random value in your database to use as user IDs.

> // get the public key object
> const publicKeyBytes = authData.slice(55 + credentialIdLength);

Extensions [may follow](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#authenticator-data) the public key and this would pick them up. That might be fine if your CBOR decoder ignores trailing data. (You can also get the public key by calling [`getPublicKey`](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#dom-authenticatorattestationresponse-getpublickey) on the attestation response, and you don't have to deal with CBOR that way.)

Comment: Yes, they are the same value :(

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand:

When you create the credential, you're using Windows Hello and not a security key? The credential ID returned matches what you're passing into the assertion call on the same machine, but Hello isn't recognising it and thinks that it must be on a security key?

If so, can you log the base64 of the whole authdata and give me that, plus the credential ID that you're getting from it?

Comment: `getPublicKey` function is good. It seems you know your stuff when it comes to webauthn. Do you know of a better tutorial than webauthn.guide or maybe want to write yourself? Their tutorial seems outdated/incomplete.

Comment: > Do you know of a better tutorial than webauthn.guide or maybe want to write yourself?

I'm not claiming that it's "better" because I've not read webauthn.guide, but I have previously written https://www.imperialviolet.org/2022/09/22/passkeys.html